# Umbraco 7.4 cannot delete or unpublish

Tags: umbraco7

I just updated my website to the latest version of umbraco (7.4.3) and I can't unpublish or delete any document. Here is the error message I get when I try to do it:

> An error occured
>
> Method not found: 'Void Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService..ctor()'.
>
> EXCEPTION DETAILS
>
> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
>   Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService..ctor()'. STACKTRACE
>
> at
>   Phm.Ccesg20.WebSvc.Extensions.EventHandlers.ContentServiceOnUnPublishing(IPublishingStrategy
>   sender, PublishEventArgs`1 e)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Events.EventExtensions.IsRaisedEventCancelled[TSender,TArgs](TypedEventHandler`2
>   eventHandler, TArgs args, TSender sender)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Publishing.PublishingStrategy.UnPublishInternal(IContent
>   content, Int32 userId)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Publishing.PublishingStrategy.UnPublish(IContent content,
>   Int32 userId)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService.UnPublishDo(IContent content,
>   Boolean omitCacheRefresh, Int32 userId)    at
>   Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService.Umbraco.Core.Services.IContentServiceOperations.UnPublish(IContent
>   content, Int32 userId)

I only use the admin panel to do actions and I don't use Umbraco API to add extra actions while publishing / unpublishing.

I can save and publish.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents,

After upgrade, check if ALL the dlls are of the correct version
May be checking with the list of plugins you are using may help